# This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK, Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have XCode installed preview 5 and need to publish an update to an app.

By posting get the following error:

> This bundle is invalid. Currently Apple is not accepting applications
>   built with this version of the SDK, Xcode.

I've looked about, and has several similar questions, but none solves the case.

As I understand it, the apple does not accept apps compiled in XCode versions preview. Is this true?

If so, what do I do? since my project no longer opens in XCode 4.5

This is lack of respect for the developer

Comment: Did you read the big yellow box of information when you downloaded Xcode 5? It clearly states that developer previews of Xcode can't be used to submit apps to the store.

Comment: And what else would xcode is not compiling and submitting apps to the apple store? It's like having a Pedrao installed, it serves no purpose. I thought that was intuita release a preview so we could fix some bugs before launch.

Comment: you are right, it is for beta testing but in adition you have to remember that beta versions are not ment for uploading apps. sorry pal, it apple.:)

Comment: It is very, very clearly stated that 5 can't be used to submit to the App Store. That's not a lack of respect. It's your mistake, not Apple's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really had the warning in iOS dev center:

> 5 Xcode Developer Preview can not be used to submit apps to the iOS or
>   Mac App Store. Continue to use the publicly released version of Xcode
>   to compile and submit apps to the App Store.

However, given the circumstances, I did not see cause to release a preview if the developer can not work on him. It's like having a stone installed on your computer.

I corrected some bugs in my apps using XCode 5, but the time to publish this disappointment had to get worse not open the project in Xcode 4.6 was more a nuisance giant.

With this I learned, I will not longer use XCode versions preview, wait the final version to fix compatibility issues with new versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Open your back up and take the copy of your project that does not include these fixes or the conversion to xcode 5 and put it in your current projects folder. Reinstall xcode 4 and voila, you are back to work.

You do keep back ups?